# pdflatex fails to compile a simple tizk code for a simple tree

Tags: pdftex, tikz-trees

I tried to pdflatex the following simple tikz code for drawing a small tree. The error message I got reads

> Package tikz Error: giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

The semicolon is actually in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,graphs}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\tikz [grow=right]
\node { ";" }
child { \node{x = 12}
}
child { \node{y = 13}
}
;
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In the child nodes, write `node` instead of `\node`.

Comment: @gernot Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Done.

Answer (score 1):

For the child nodes in a `tikz` tree, use `node` instead of `\node`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz [grow=right]
  \node { ``;'' }          % \node command ends at semicolon below
    child { node{x = 12} } % use node instead of \node
    child { node{y = 13} };% use node instead of \node
\end{document}
```